# Change cell color based on value faster

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba code to change the color of cells based on the content of it currently I am looping through 13000 cells individually using row and column indexed for loops and a select case statement but it takes around 30 secs. Does anyone know a quicker way ?

Comment: No, it's a color coded map conditional formatting is volitile and calculates all the time making the spread sheet clunky the values only need to change once and update colours

Comment: I assume you're doing that standard things like turning off screenupdating during the looping etc?

Comment: i would use autofilter and special cells.  would be a breeze.

Comment: It is a breeze with auto filter however the 13000 cells are split into 103 columns and there are 15 criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect reading each value from the cell is taking up a large chunk of the time. Try reading the data into an array and then creating 15 ranges, one for each colour. You'd then just fill each range with the appropriate colour at the end.

Having said that, 13,000 cells to colour is going to take some time. I couldn't get better than 10 seconds. If you only have to do it once though, 30 seconds doesn't seem so bad?

```
Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, rOff As Long, cOff As Long
Dim data As Variant
Dim dataRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim colourRanges(14) As Range
Dim colours(14) As Long

'Define the colours
colours(0) = 255
colours(1) = 65535
colours(2) = 5296274
colours(3) = 12611584
colours(4) = 10498160
colours(5) = 49407
colours(6) = 192
colours(7) = 5287936
colours(8) = 15773696
colours(9) = 6299648
colours(10) = 5540756
colours(11) = 9803737
colours(12) = 13083058
colours(13) = 9486586
colours(14) = 14474738

'Define the target range
With Sheet1
    Set dataRange = .Range(.Range("A2"), _
                           .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
                    .Resize(, 103)
End With

'Calculate offsets from "A1"
With dataRange
    rOff = .Cells(1).Row - 1
    cOff = .Cells(1).Column - 1
End With

'Read data
data = dataRange.Value2


'Test the data
For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        Select Case data(r, c)
            Case 1: i = 0
            Case 2: i = 1
            Case 3: i = 2
            Case 4: i = 3
            Case 5: i = 4
            Case 6: i = 5
            Case 7: i = 6
            Case 8: i = 7
            Case 9: i = 8
            Case 10: i = 9
            Case 11: i = 10
            Case 12: i = 11
            Case 13: i = 12
            Case 14: i = 13
            Case 15: i = 14
            Case Else: i = -1
        End Select

        'Build the colour ranges
        If i <> -1 Then
            With Sheet1
                Set cell = .Cells(r + rOff, c + cOff)
                If colourRanges(i) Is Nothing Then
                    Set colourRanges(i) = cell
                Else
                    Set colourRanges(i) = Union(colourRanges(i), cell)
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next

'Colour the ranges
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 0 To 14
    colourRanges(i).Interior.Color = colours(i)
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1):

this is some sample code I had from another question.  you should be able to see how easy it is to set up the autofilter and once it is filtered by your criteria just do the interior.colorindex for whatever color you want to set for the visible cells then change criteria for next color rinse and repeat. i also recommend to turn calculation to manual at beginning of sub along with screenupdating false and enable events false then at end of sub set calculation back to automatic and make other two things true again.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim IMBacklogSh As Worksheet, logoffSh As Worksheet, deniedsh As Worksheet

Set IMBacklogSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backlog")
Set logoffSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Claims Logged off")
Set deniedsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Claims Denied")

With IMBacklogSh
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        .AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:="C"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                .Copy Destination:= _
                    logoffSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                'optionally delete the originals
                .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:="<>C"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                .Copy Destination:= _
                    deniedsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                'optionally delete the originals
                .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    End With
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I used a simpler autofilter code that took 119 seconds but I shall give this one a go

Comment: make sure you turn off calculations prior to filter by setting them to manual like this: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual and turn back on after filter like this:  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic.  also set screenupdating to false if you didn't already.

Comment: I will give this sample a try and feedback timings

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps sorting by the criteria you color code by, then changing ranges, and finally flipping back to original sequence perhaps. Sort it in such a way as the ones that would not need changing color appear at the end.. Then you can quit faster...

Comment: I will give that a try

Answer (score 0):

use a range for each color. Put the cells in a vba array. In a loop you build each 'color range' but do not color the ranges yet. After the loop, each 'color range' receives its color accordingly. Voila. Basicaly

Comment: What do you mean Viola?